# Identify Zipp hub version

Tags: zipp

Which version / year is this 303 Firecrest hub?
The hub has this number: 11sp z3001 13 0863 and the wheel is tubular

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To identify the wheel from the serial number you will probably have to contact Zipp customer support.
However they do have some useful pages on their website with quite detailed descriptions to help identify their products.

[Hub Timeline](https://www.zipp.com/support/identify/hub_timeline.php)

[Wheel Timeline](https://www.zipp.com/support/identify/wheel_timeline.php)

Comment: Contacted the customer support. They were very helpful.